# ionic app flow release ended up with draft mode in Google play console

Tags: google-play-console, ionic-appflow

We have configured Ionic App flow for streamline our development process. But I have come across some issue with internal testing flow in google play store.

Every time we push the commit , it triggers the **build** , **package** and **Upload** in to play store

But this flow ended up with Draft mode in Release dashboard.

In order to roll out the update we need to logging to Play console and do it by manually.

Is there any way to automate this through app flow?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best thing to do for now is to just setup [Appflow Live Updates](https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/deploy/intro) that bypass Google play console and App Store completely, updating the app's JS layer instantly. Which you should be using most of the time anyway.

Then, when it comes to updating the native Android Layer, looks like for now you just have to go in and manually hit the rollout button. At least until Google adds a setting for us.

Here's a thread on [Ionic's forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-play-automatically-publish-releases/207463) talking about this.